# Alternative For Stored Procedures In cockroachDB

Tags: database, stored-procedures, migration, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I was trying to migrate from Another RDBMS to cockroachDB but I think there is no such functionality like stored procedures in Cockroach. So what is the best alternative to make a stored procedure in cockroachDB ?

Comment: can you please describe the use case you are trying to achieve with Stored Procedures? Many a time Stored Procedures create a lock-in into a DB vendor.

Comment: For now just the basic sample stored procedures I m trying to see what are limitations and capabilities of cockroach... that's it ....So if I want to use it for a transaction purpose whether i will be able to do that or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CockroachDB [does not support stored procedures](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/postgresql-compatibility.html#unsupported-postgresql-features) and the best alternative would depend on the problem you are trying to solve. A few examples:

- If the stored procedure contains business logic, we'd recommend moving that logic to the application.
- Simple stored procedures that contain a single DML statement should be moved into the application's DataAccess logic.
- More complex stored procedures that contain explicit transactions or error code should be moved to the application-level transactions.

EDIT: [Stored Procedures as a Litmus Test](https://medium.com/@JoeEmison/stored-procedures-as-a-litmus-test-c7ec772b985e), an article by Joe Emison, compares Stored Procedures to other solutions. It may be helpful in understanding alternatives.

Comment: I'm gonna say I found that "stored procedures as a litmus test" to be a pretty terrible read. The expressiveness of stored procedures has enormous benefits in some use cases and I've been promoting them ever since I discovered that I could get 100x performance and better reliability with 1/10th LOC relative to the equivalent application in Java or Go. YMMV, but there are plenty of benefits to stored procedures and I for one would love to find something as expressive, hosted or not.

Answer (score 0):

CockroachDB is distributed SQL and natively suits serverless patterns.  As a stored proc is just a way to ensure procedural consistency, you could probably get by using serverless functions (whatever flavor).  The idea is the serverless function is a proxy for the stored procedure.

While it is possible for a procs to call other procs, common advice is to avoid having serverless functions call each other.  It would be reasonable to develop a cloud library (JavaScript, for example) which models all the DB constraints.  Then each serverless function becomes an endpoint (proc) and the library provides the means to reuse/shared logic.